# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit always centers the UIImageView, either vertically or horizontally. Can it not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Pretty simple question. UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit always centers the UIImageView in its frame either vertically or horizontally. Is it possible to offset that?

Comment: No, because otherwise it wouldn't be aspect fitting. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Say it's aligned in the vertical center, I might want it at the vertical top. It would still fit to its aspect.

Answer (score 0):

> Say it's aligned in the vertical center, I might want it at the vertical top. It would still fit to its aspect.

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a container view for the image view, and move your image view within the container.

You would still need to aspect fit the image, but you would need some additional logic to alter the frame of your image view depending on the aspect ratio of the image itself, and the size of the frame you are fitting it into. You can get this from the `size` property of the image.